# What happens when a .NET thread throws an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

We have an interface IPoller for which we have various implementations.  We have a process that will take an IPoller and start it in a separate thread.  I'm trying to come up with a generic way of providing exception handling for any IPollers which don't do it themselves.

My original thinking was to create an implementation of IPoller that would accept an IPoller and just provide some logging functionality.  The question I ran into though is how would I provide this error handling?  If I have IPoller.Start() which is the target for the Thread is that where the exception will occur?  Or is there something on the thread itself I can hook into?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate() {
    try
    {
        MyIPoller.Start();
    }
    catch(ThreadAbortException)
    {
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //handle
    }
    finally
    {
    }
});
```

This will ensure the exception doesn't make it to the top of the thread.

Comment: You may also want to catch the AppDomainUnloadedException. MSDN: An AppDomainUnloadedException is thrown in a thread because the application domain in which the thread is executing is being unloaded.

Comment: I understand you explained about how to prevent the exception from crossing the thread but the question title says "what happens if it does".. Any pointers on that.?

Answer (score 13):

You should catch the exception at the method you use at the top of the thread, and do the logging from there.

An unhandled exception (at the top of a thread) will (in 2.0 onwards) kill your process. Not good.

i.e. whatever method you pass to `Thread.Start` (etc) should have a `try`/`catch`, and do something useful in the `catch` (logging, perhaps graceful shutdown, etc).

To achieve this, you could use:

- static logging methods
- captured variables into the delegate (as an anonymous method)
- expose your method on an instance that already knows about the logger

Answer (score 8):

In .NET 4.0+ you should use Tasks instead of threads. [Here's a nice article](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/31/9674669.aspx) on exception handling in Task Parallel Library

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx), it will help you at least log those exceptions that you are not handling, and in some cases close down "nicely":

> This event provides notification of
>   uncaught exceptions. It allows the
>   application to log information about
>   the exception before the system
>   default handler reports the exception
>   to the user and terminates the
>   application. If sufficient information
>   about the state of the application is
>   available, other actions may be
>   undertaken — such as saving program
>   data for later recovery. Caution is
>   advised, because program data can
>   become corrupted when exceptions are
>   not handled.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

> [Appdomain.FirstChanceException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It tells you moment any exception occurs and CLR is looking for stack trace. Also event args tell which type of exception. You can consider it as the central place for logging.